# How to implement username password authenticator for RPyC server

Tags: python, python-3.x, rpc, rpyc

I am trying to secure my RpyC server connections through username and password. The documentation indeed shows an [example](https://rpyc.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/utils_authenticators.html#), but it is too brief. No details were given on how exactly the password is passed from the client-side. Anyone figured out how to do that? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi, I have a similar need now. Have you came up with any solution/suggestion?

Comment: @ylcnky I put that on hold since I am the only consumer of my rpyc service. You can look at [SSL based authenticators](https://rpyc.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/utils_authenticators.html#rpyc.utils.authenticators.SSLAuthenticator). But at high level I feel we need to override some rpyc internal methods  on the client side and send the auth info. For example this might be a qualified [entry point](https://github.com/tomerfiliba-org/rpyc/blob/7ea2d24ab70840fb1324c0d5c8b052fcaca7f635/rpyc/core/stream.py#L121) since ``rpyc.connect`` creates a SocketStream object.

Comment: @ylcnky I got curious and tested me theory, I posted an answer. I hope it will help you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Answering my own question:

I had to override some internal methods of RPyC on the client side to achieve the desired behaviour. I don't know if much cleaner solution exists, but this seems to be a plausible one.

**Server:**

```
import rpyc
from rpyc.utils.authenticators import AuthenticationError

def magic_word_authenticator(sock):
    if sock.recv(5).decode() != "Ma6ik":
        raise AuthenticationError("wrong magic word")
    return sock, None

class SecuredService(rpyc.Service):

    def exposed_secured_op(self):
        return 'Secret String'

rpyc.ThreadedServer(
    service=SecuredService, hostname='localhost',
    port=18812, authenticator=magic_word_authenticator
).start()
```

**Client:**

```
import rpyc
import traceback


class AuthSocketStream(rpyc.SocketStream):

    @classmethod
    def connect(cls, *args, authorizer=None, **kwargs):
        stream_obj =  super().connect(*args, **kwargs)

        if callable(authorizer):
            authorizer(stream_obj.sock)

        return stream_obj


def rpyc_connect(host, port, service=rpyc.VoidService, config={}, ipv6=False, keepalive=False, authorizer=None):
    s = AuthSocketStream.connect(
            host, port, ipv6=ipv6, keepalive=keepalive,
            authorizer=authorizer
    )

    return rpyc.connect_stream(s, service, config)

print('With correct authorizer')

conn1 = rpyc_connect(
        'localhost', 18812, authorizer=lambda sock: sock.send('Ma6ik'.encode())
)

print(conn1.root.secured_op())

print('With wrong authorizer')

conn2 = rpyc_connect(
        'localhost', 18812, authorizer=lambda sock: sock.send('Invalid'.encode())
)

try:
    conn2.root
except Exception:
    print(traceback.format_exc())


print('With no authorizer')

conn3 = rpyc_connect(
        'localhost', 18812
)

try:
    conn3.root
except Exception:
    print(traceback.format_exc())
```

**Client Console Log:**

```
With correct authorizer
Secret String
With wrong authorizer
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/client.py", line 40, in <module>
    conn2.root
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/rpyc/core/protocol.py", line 507, in root
    self._remote_root = self.sync_request(consts.HANDLE_GETROOT)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/rpyc/core/protocol.py", line 474, in sync_request
    return self.async_request(handler, *args, timeout=timeout).value
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/rpyc/core/async_.py", line 101, in value
    self.wait()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/rpyc/core/async_.py", line 48, in wait
    self._conn.serve(self._ttl)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/rpyc/core/protocol.py", line 387, in serve
    data = self._channel.poll(timeout) and self._channel.recv()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/rpyc/core/channel.py", line 55, in recv
    header = self.stream.read(self.FRAME_HEADER.size)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/rpyc/core/stream.py", line 260, in read
    raise EOFError("connection closed by peer")
EOFError: connection closed by peer

With no authorizer
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/client.py", line 52, in <module>
    conn3.root
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/rpyc/core/protocol.py", line 507, in root
    self._remote_root = self.sync_request(consts.HANDLE_GETROOT)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/rpyc/core/protocol.py", line 474, in sync_request
    return self.async_request(handler, *args, timeout=timeout).value
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/rpyc/core/async_.py", line 101, in value
    self.wait()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/rpyc/core/async_.py", line 48, in wait
    self._conn.serve(self._ttl)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/rpyc/core/protocol.py", line 387, in serve
    data = self._channel.poll(timeout) and self._channel.recv()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/rpyc/core/channel.py", line 55, in recv
    header = self.stream.read(self.FRAME_HEADER.size)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/rpyc/core/stream.py", line 260, in read
    raise EOFError("connection closed by peer")
EOFError: connection closed by peer
```

Comment: Great! thank you so much for the share. It looks like it will help.